# How can I make Quicksilver cmd-esc auto-tab to action/predicate pane?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, quicksilver

This is a *really* finicky question, but in my old version of QS, if I hit cmd-esc to pull a file into the quicksilver object pane, it auto-invoked in the action / predicate pane so I could just start typing the command right away. Now I have to wait until QS invokes and hit tab, which is admittedly not the end of the world, but it was nice when it auto-invoked in the second pane. Any thoughts? QS ß59 and OS X 10.6.7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the "Focus action when displaying results" setting under the Command preferences section.